# Вывести массив коротким образом в String

Tags: javascript

Есть массив,числа это типа номера маршруток на данном улице.Числа идут только на возрастание и по порядку.

> [1,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,13,14,17]

Нужно чтобы те числа которые последовательны друг другу по 1 -

> (3,4,5,6)(12,13,14)

были написаны таким образом -

> (3-6)(12-14)

И в итоге получать такой String -

> 1,3-6,8,10,12-14,17

Еще примеры массивов -

> [10,11,12] 10-12
>
> [1,2,3,4,5,9] 1-5,9

У меня неполноценный код.

```js
function solution(x) {
  let y = [];
  let min;
  let max;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] - x[i - 1] == 1) {
      y.push(x[i])
    }
  }
  y.unshift(y[0] - 1);
  min = y[0];
  max = y[y.length - 1];
  y = [min, max];
  y = y.toString().split(",").join("-");
  return y
}
console.log(solution([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8])) //3-6
console.log(solution([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12])) //3-12
```

Comment: Числа всегда только на возрастание и по порядку идут?

Comment: @UModeL Да,только на возрастание и по порядку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Много разного можно придумать, например так:

```js
function print(arr) {
  // для пустого массива проще сразу вернуть результат
  if (!arr.length) {  
    return '';
  }
  
  return arr
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)  // сортируем как числа (если нужно)
    // итерируемся по массиву, накапливаем результат
    // learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#reduce-reduceright
    .reduce((intervals, value, index) => {
      // первый элемент мы уже обработали - см. ниже
      if (!index) { 
        return intervals;
      }

      // intervals - массив непрерывных интервалов,
      // берём последний элемент последнего массива
      const interval = intervals[intervals.length - 1];
      const last = interval[interval.length - 1];

      // текущий элемент входит в последний интервал?
      if (value - last === 1) {  
        interval.push(value);
      } else {  // создаём новый (следующий) интервал
        intervals.push([value]);
      }

      return intervals;  // reduce требует возращать накопитель
    }, [  // начальное значение для intervals — первый интервал
      [arr[0]]
    ])
    // итерируемся, превращаем каждый интервал
    // в его строковое представление
    .map(interval => {
      if (interval.length > 1) {  // диапазон
        return `${interval[0]}-${interval[interval.length - 1]}`;
      } else {  // в интервале всего один элемент 
        return String(interval[0]);
      }
    })
    .join();  // склеиваем через запятые
}
console.log(print([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12]))
```

Comment: а если попроще?))))

Comment: добавь описание, что происходит в коде.

Comment: @TyomArshakyan добавил поясняющие комментарии.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @TyomArshakyan, а как ты разобрался со скрытым тестом?